# Weird white border at bottom of JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have this weird white border at the bottom of my screen. It's on the bottom left corner, which is the TimeView.java

[image]

This is my ContentPane.java

```
package views;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ContentPane extends JPanel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private GameView gameView;
private PlayView playView;
private TimeView timeView;

public ContentPane() {      
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
}

public void setGameView(GameView gameView, PlayView playView, TimeView timeView) {
    this.gameView = gameView;
    this.playView = playView;
    this.timeView = timeView;

    JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();
    subPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(subPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    subPanel.add(gameView);
    subPanel.add(timeView);

    this.add(playView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(subPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
}

}
```

This is GameView.java

```
package views;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GameView extends JPanel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public GameView() {
    this.setBackground(Color.decode("#2A2828"));
    this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 5, 0, Color.GRAY));
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 300));
}

}
```

This is TimeView.java

```
package views;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class TimeView extends JPanel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public TimeView() {
    this.setBackground(Color.decode("#2A2828"));
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 500));
}
}
```

And this is PlayView.java

```
package views;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PlayView extends JPanel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public PlayView() {
    this.setBackground(Color.decode("#1F1F40"));
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1100, 800));
}

}
```

I've already tried putting an empty border on the TimeView but still,​ I'm getting the weird white border.

If anyone could explain to me what causes this problem that'd be great.

EDIT:

This is MainFrame.java

```
package views;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void setupGui(ContentPane contentPane) {
    this.setTitle("TagMan By Jesse");
    this.setContentPane(contentPane);
    this.setSize(1300, 800);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setResizable(false);
}
```

}

Comment: could you post the code from which you call setVisible(true) on a JFrame?

Comment: @BabaNew I've edited my post.

Comment: Calling `this.setResizable(false);` after `setSize` is your primary issue, although, relying on `setSize` is also a bad idea

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've deleted `this.setResizable(false);` but the problem still exists. Why shouldn't I use `setSize` btw?

Comment: @idontunderstandarrays You shouldn't use `setSize` as the available content size is the window size MINUS the decorations.  You should make use of the layout management API and `Window#pack`, which will "pack" the window around the content at it's preferred size.  As I understand it, you "might" be a victim of `int` rounding, where (something like `BoxLayout`) is attempting to calculate the available space and it's resulting in a float point value which is then rounded down to an `int` automatically ... it's all just a mess

Comment: @idontunderstandarrays When I use `pack`, I get a frame size of `1300x822`

Comment: @idontunderstandarrays [BoxLayout leaves pixel line at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289569/boxlayout-leaves-pixel-line-at-the-bottom)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ooh sorry thought I searched the whole internet and still didn't find it. Why do you think it's still 1300x822 instead of the max 1300x822?

Comment: @idontunderstandarrays The window's title bar is `22` pixels high.  The "desired" height is `800`, so it's `800 + 22` high - which is why you should use `pack` ;). Note on Windows those calculations are MUCH more complicated - so use `pack` ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ooh that won't matter. The contentpane needs to be 1300x800. Thanks for all your help man, understand it a bit better now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On many OS's making a window not resizable changes the frame decorations, which affects the available content space.  This tends to NOT invalidate the container though, which can result in a small amount of additional space been unused.

You should call `setResizable` BEFORE setting the size or making the window visible.

Also, because the "available" space is the "window size" MINUS the "frame decorations", you shouldn't rely on `setSize`, instead, you should allow the window and the layout manager API to make this determination for you and simply call `pack`, which will pack the window around the contents preferred size, for example...

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new ContentPane());
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ContentPane extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private GameView gameView;
        private PlayView playView;
        private TimeView timeView;

        public ContentPane() {
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setGameView(new GameView(), new PlayView(), new TimeView());
        }

        public void setGameView(GameView gameView, PlayView playView, TimeView timeView) {
            this.gameView = gameView;
            this.playView = playView;
            this.timeView = timeView;

            JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();
            subPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(subPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            subPanel.add(gameView);
            subPanel.add(timeView);

            this.add(playView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            this.add(subPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        }

    }

    public class GameView extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public GameView() {
            this.setBackground(Color.decode("#2A2828"));
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 5, 0, Color.GRAY));
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 300));
        }

    }

    public class TimeView extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public TimeView() {
            this.setBackground(Color.decode("#2A2828"));
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 500));
        }
    }

    public class PlayView extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public PlayView() {
            this.setBackground(Color.decode("#1F1F40"));
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1100, 800));
        }

    }
}
```

I'd also discourage the use of `setPreferredSize` in favour of overriding `getPreferredSize`, as `setPreferredSize` doesn't provide a suitable means to "manage" any changes which might occur

Comment: I got it! I deleted the `setSize` and added the `.pack`. How would I go about doing `getPreferredSize` instead of `setPreferredSize`. Thanks a lot man :)

Comment: Simply add `public Dimension getPreferredSize() {...}` to each class and return the `Dimension` you want to use (instead of using `setPreferredSize`)